# Problems with Python tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am a noob in programming who tried to study machine learning. I used tensorflow for Python. Here's the code, written (but **not 100% copied**) with official tensorflow guide (here's it https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/basics). I can't see the final graph with the results after training. I've tried two methods of training and both share the same problem. Could anyone help me?

```
import matplotlib as mp
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

mp.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20, 10]
precision = 500
x = tf.linspace(-10.0, 10.0, precision)


def y(x): return 4 * np.sin(x - 1) + 3

newY = y(x) + tf.random.normal(shape=[precision])

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = units, activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.random.normal, bias_initializer=tf.random.normal)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    
    def __call__(self, x, training = True):
        x = x[:, tf.newaxis]
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        return tf.squeeze(x, axis=1)

model = Model(164)

pl.plot(x, y(x), label = "origin")
pl.plot(x, newY, ".", label = "corrupted")
pl.plot(x, model(x), label = "before training")

"""                                                     The first method
vars = model.variables
optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.01)

for i in range(1000):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        prediction = model(x)
        error = (newY-prediction)**2
        mean_error = tf.reduce_mean(error)
    gradient = tape.gradient(mean_error, vars)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradient, vars))
"""

model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE, optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = 0.01))
model.fit(x, newY, epochs=100,batch_size=32,verbose=0)

pl.plot(x, model(x), label = "after training")
pl.legend()
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and investigated it. Your model returns NaN loss during training, I removed kernel and bias initializers and it works. For now I don't know what's wrong with your initialization. It seems that some weights got initialized with NaNs which then made the predictions become NaNs, hence you couldn't plot them.

Update: use the initializers module (like `tensorflow.initializers` or `tensorflow.keras.initializers`, not `tensorflow.random`). For example, use `kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal` instead of what you have.

Comment: Thanks, this time I at least have a graph, but It's very close to a straight line, so it looks like it's learning is very inefficient. Can you see any others mistakes?

Comment: I don't see any other mistakes. If your predictions are very close to a straight line then probably your model is underfitting. There are many ways to make it better but that's a question for another topic.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will ask this as a new question. For now, goodbye!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your third graph and your fourth graph are the same. They are
`pl.plot(x, model(x), label = "before training")` and `pl.plot(x, model(x), label = "after training")` You can figure out that the x-axis and y-axis data of two graphs are the same.

Hope my answer is helpful to you!

Comment: No, that's wrong, one of these graphs shows data at one moment, and next appears after a few lines of code, which were intended to change this data (simplified explanation to my code). And I still can't see this grapn even after removing ```pl.plot(x, model(x), label = "before training")```

Comment: What is your model(x) data? If it is y-axis data after training your original x-axis data,  I suggest you store your model(x) data into a variable and then print it out to see whether it is the data you want.